# Help with a proof in Hartshorne's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I'm struggling to understand this part of the proof of this proposition:

[image]
[image]

I'm having troubles only in this part, I really need help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because $\varphi$ is a morphism of sheaves, the fact that $\varphi(V_P)(s(P)) = t|_{V_P}$ implies that $\varphi(V_P \cap V_Q)(s(P)|_{V_P \cap V_Q}) = t|_{V_P \cap V_Q}$.  To be maximally explicit, this comes from commutativity of
$$\begin{array}{ccc} \mathcal{F}(V_P) & \stackrel{\varphi(V_P)}{\longrightarrow } & \mathcal{G}(V_P) \\
\downarrow && \downarrow \\
\mathcal{F}(V_P \cap V_Q) &\stackrel{\varphi(V_P\cap V_Q)}{\longrightarrow }  & \mathcal{G}(V_P \cap V_Q) \end{array}$$

where the vertical maps are restrictions. **Look again at the definition of a sheaf morphism!** Similarly $\varphi(V_P \cap V_Q)(s(Q)|_{V_P \cap V_Q}) = t|_{v_P \cap v_Q}$. Hence $\varphi(V_P \cap V_Q)$ sends $s(P)|_{V_P\cap V_Q}$ and $s(Q)|_{V_P\cap V_Q}$ to the same thing.

Comment: But $\varphi=\varphi(U)$? what exactly is $\varphi$?

Comment: I'm confused, you use $\varphi$ to denote $\varphi (V_p)$ and $\varphi (V_P\cap V_Q)$ in the same time.

Comment: @user42912 Look again at the definition of $\varphi$; it is a collection of maps for every open set.

Comment: yes, yes I understood thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

The main point here is that morphisms of sheaves commute with restriction.

You have $\varphi(s(P)|_{V_P})=t|_{V_P}$, and $s(P)|_{V_P\cap V_Q}=(s(P)|_{V_P})|_{V_Q}$ (this is essentially one of the axioms of presheaves). So

$$\varphi(s(P)|_{V_P\cap V_Q})=\varphi(s|_{v_P})|_{V_Q}=(t|_{V_P})|_{V_Q}=t|_{V_P\cap V_Q}$$

Then you can do the same thing with $P$ and $Q$ interchanged to get $\varphi(s(Q)|_{V_P\cap V_Q})=t|_{V_P\cap V_Q}$.

Comment: Minor nitpick in the second sentence: It's actually more generally one of the axioms of a presheaf. +1 Nonetheless.

Comment: @user38268 Ha, that is a fairly extreme level of pedantry! ;-) But it is indeed true that if you want to find the axiom I mean, you probably need to look up presheaves, so edited.

Comment: What exactly is $\varphi$? can I say that $\varphi (U)=\varphi$? thank you.

Comment: @user42912 $\varphi$ is a collection of maps $\varphi(U)\colon\mathscr{F}(U)\to\mathscr{G}(U)$ for each open $U$, but the $(U)$ isn't always written to simplify the notation. All of the sections you consider are defined over open subsets of $U$, so everything makes sense when you replace $\varphi$ by $\varphi(U)$ again.

Comment: I'm sorry but I couldn't understand why $s(P)|_{V_P\cap V_Q}=(s(P)|_{V_P})|_{V_Q}$

Comment: @user42912 For your last comment: Look at the axioms for a presheaf!

Comment: @user42912 One possible point of confusion is that I cheated - $V_Q$ isn't contained in $V_P$ in general, so the right hand side should really have a $|_{V_P\cap V_Q}$ instead of $|_{V_Q}$. Then it's the axiom of presheaves that says restricting twice is the same as restricting all the way to the smallest set in one go.

Comment: yes, thank you very much.