# Doubt in Hartshorne's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

After to post this question: [Help with a proof in Hartshorne's book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496480/help-with-a-proof-in-hartshornes-book) I realized that I have another doubt in this proof:

[image]
[image]

What I know is

$\varphi_p(s_p)=t_p\implies (\varphi_{V_p}(s(P))_p=t_p$

I don't understand why $(\varphi_{V_p}(s(P))_p=(t_{|V_P})_p$

**NOTATION:**

Instead of $\varphi(V_P)$, to simplify notation I write $\varphi_{V_P}$

Sorry to post the same proof again

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Recall the definition of the stalk - it answers your question directly. My advice is not to read this Proposition step my step as if it is was a purely algebraic argument. Instead, do it on your own and use pictures. Really, you can prove this Proposition just using pictures, and thereby gain a lot of intuition for the subject. I would explain it to you if we were in front of a blackboard. :)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Unfortunately I don't have maturity in this field yet to use pictures.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg maybe there is some typo or simplification in the notation I don't see?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg please can you see my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the morphisms

- $\rho_{X/V_P}:\mathcal{G}(X)\to\mathcal{G}(V_P)$
- $\sigma_{V_P/P}:\mathcal{G}(V_P) \to \mathcal{G}_P$
- $\sigma_{X/P}:\mathcal{G}(X)\to\mathcal{G}_P$

It follows from the definition of a stalk that $\sigma_{X/P}=\sigma_{V_P/P}\circ\rho_{X/V_P}$ because $V_P$ and $X$ are both open neighborhoods of $P$. Look up the definition of a [direct limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) to confirm this, if you like.

In other words, the above statement means $t_P=(t|_{V_P})_P$. Now given what you know, this yields what you want to understand.

**Edit** I would write it down as follows: We may replace $V_P$ by $V_P\cap U$, then $V_P$ is an open subset contained in both $V_P$ and $U$. Hence, we have $t_P=(t|_{V_P})_P$. Thus,
 $\varphi_P(s_P)=t_P$ implies $(\varphi_{V_P}(s(P)))_P=t_P=(t|_{V_P})_P$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, please can you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Lema 1**

Let $V\subset U$ and $t\in \mathcal F(U)$, we have $(t_{|V})_p=t_p$

*Proof*

$(t_{|V})_p=t_p \Leftrightarrow \exists \ W\subset V\cap U=V;\ t_{|W}=(t_{|V})_{|W}$, but

$(t_{|V})_{|W}=t_{|W}$

**Proof of the question:**

$\varphi_P(s(P))=t_P\implies (\text{by definition of}\ \varphi_P)\\ (\varphi_{V_P}(s(P)))_P=t_P\implies\\ \exists\ W\subset V_P\cap U=V_P; (\varphi_{V_P}(s(P)))_{|W}=t_{|W}\implies \ (\text{since} \ t_{|W}=(t_{|V_P})_{|W})\\(\varphi_{V_P}(s(P)))_{|W}=(t_{|V_P})_{|W}\implies\\ ((\varphi_{V_P}(s(P)))_{|W})_P=((t_{|V_P})_{|W})_P\implies\text{(Lemma 1)}\\ (\varphi_{V_P}(s(P)))_P=((t_{|V_P}))_P$

Comment: This looks correct, but it does use quite a large amount of brackets. I think this can be seen very easily in diagram language, while the above is hard to read.